# how to grab a WPF TextBlock using teststack

Tags: wpf, white-framework, teststack

I made a WPF app, and have made some automated tests using teststack.white.  They have documentation on how they map controls in Windows to their framework but I don't see TextBlock there anywhere.

Their docs are [here](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.docs/blob/master/_source/White/UIItems.md) and [here](http://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UIItems/).

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are not mistaken, there's no mention of `TextBlock` there.

The thing is the `TextBlock` is just a longer `Label` in WPF, as you can read [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control/):

> A common understanding is that a Label is for short, one-line texts
>   (but may include e.g. an image), while the TextBlock works very well
>   for multiline strings as well, but can only contain text (strings).

So you can just get it as you would do with a `Label`:

```
Application application = Application.Launch(applicationPath);
Window window = application.GetWindows().First();

var MyTextBlock = window.Get<Label>("MyTextBlock");
```

This is the XAML markup I used to test it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="103.966" Width="191.724">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="Hello!" Background="CornflowerBlue" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could you have a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500604/teststack-how-to-find-custom-controls-and-invoke-methods-fire-events thanks 